# Plot top n metrics from a pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

In a pandas dataframe, if I create a pivot and plot based on the column, how can I restrict the number of columns being plotted based on a aggregated function.

Example,

Suppose I have a dataframe pivot as

```
         sum                        
name     'a'     'b'     'c'     'd'
key                                 
1          1       2       3       4
2          1       2       3       4
3          1       2       3     nan
```

which I plot as

[image]

Now, I would want to only plot top (2) columns based on average such that only 'c' and 'd' shows up suppressing 'a' and 'd'.

How can I achieve this using pandas?

**Input DataFrame and Plot**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = StringIO("""name;key;value
    'a';1;1
    'a';2;1
    'a';3;1
    'b';1;2
    'b';2;2
    'b';3;2
    'c';1;3
    'c';2;3
    'c';3;3
    'd';1;4
    'd';2;4
    """)
df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index='key', columns='name', values='value',aggfunc=[np.sum])
pivot.plot()
```

Comment: can you also provide the input dataframe , the code to reproduce the pivot table and the plot as well. Thanks

Comment: @anky_91 Please refer my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) of `pivot` and then find [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) with `n=2` , then using [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) , select only those columns and plot:

```
pivot.loc[:,pivot.mean().nlargest(2).index].plot()
#or pivot[pivot.mean().nlargest(2).index].plot()
```

---

[image]